# How can I merge two datasets with different frequency in their rows and preserve all information?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I have two dataframes. The first one is called 'demographics' and looks like so:

```
date_month  date_week  population  village  country
 2020-04    2020-04-06    1000        V1       C1
 2020-04    2020-04-06    1400        V2       C1
 2020-04    2020-04-06    1500        V2       C2
 2020-04    2020-04-06    1200        V3       C2
 2020-04    2020-04-13    1001        V1       C1
 2020-04    2020-04-13    1401        V2       C1
 2020-04    2020-04-13    1501        V2       C2
 2020-04    2020-04-13    1201        V3       C2
 2020-04    2020-04-20    1002        V1       C1
 2020-04    2020-04-20    1402        V2       C1
 2020-04    2020-04-20    1502        V2       C2
 2020-04    2020-04-20    1202        V3       C2
 2020-04    2020-04-27    1003        V1       C1
 2020-04    2020-04-27    1403        V2       C1
 2020-04    2020-04-27    1503        V2       C2
 2020-04    2020-04-27    1203        V3       C2
```

As you can see, **demographics has a weekly frequency for every row**. The second dataset is called 'income', **has monthly frequency**, and looks like so:

```
date_month  village   country  income  person
 2020-04      V1         C1      10     John
 2020-04      V2         C1       8     Mike
 2020-04      V2         C2       9     Sarah
 2020-04      V3         C2      10     Adam
```

**I would like to generate a weekly frequency dataframe that contains both the population and income columns while also preserving the person**. Like so:

```
date_month  village   country  income  person   date_week   population 
 2020-04      V1         C1      10     John    2020-04-06     1000
 2020-04      V2         C1       8     Mike    2020-04-06     1400
 2020-04      V2         C2       9     Sarah   2020-04-06     1500
 2020-04      V3         C2      10     Adam    2020-04-06     1200
 2020-04      V1         C1      10     John    2020-04-13     1001
 2020-04      V2         C1       8     Mike    2020-04-13     1401
 2020-04      V2         C2       9     Sarah   2020-04-13     1501
 2020-04      V3         C2      10     Adam    2020-04-13     1201
 2020-04      V1         C1      10     John    2020-04-20     1002
 2020-04      V2         C1       8     Mike    2020-04-20     1402
 2020-04      V2         C2       9     Sarah   2020-04-20     1502
 2020-04      V3         C2      10     Adam    2020-04-20     1202
 2020-04      V1         C1      10     John    2020-04-27     1003
 2020-04      V2         C1       8     Mike    2020-04-27     1403
 2020-04      V2         C2       9     Sarah   2020-04-27     1503
 2020-04      V3         C2      10     Adam    2020-04-27     1203
```

How can I do this efficiently? It would seem I need to 'multiply' and then concatenate the monthly dataset by the number of weeks in the frequency dataset, assuming there is a match in the date_month column?

Comment: Try this:  newdf = pd.merge(demographics, income, on=['date_month','village','country'])

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use pandas merge to get that result (assuming date_month is a column):

```
demographics.merge(income,on=['date_month','village','country'])
```